# Vector spaces with and without zero divisors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

I came up with the following problem. Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring, $\mathbb K$ is a subring of $R$, and also $R$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$.

There are two possibilities: $(a)$ $R$ contains zero-divisors; $(b)$ $R$ is an integral domain.

My first question: does the following statement hold in general?

$R$ contains zero-divisors $\Leftrightarrow$ $R\cong\displaystyle \prod_1^n\mathbb K$

I know that if $R$ is an integral domain under all the above assumptions then $R$ is actually a field therefore a finite extension of $\mathbb K$.

My second question: Is this true that all finite-dimensional vector spaces $R$ without zero divisors over field $\mathbb K$ are finite algebraic extensions over $\mathbb K$?

Finally, I am curious about the infinite-dimensional cases of the same problems, namely,

$R$ is a commutative ring, $\mathbb K$ is a subring of $R$, and $R$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$. Then is it true that: $R$ contains zero-divisors $\Leftrightarrow$ $R\cong\displaystyle \prod_1^\infty\mathbb K$ and that all infinite-dimensional vector spaces $R$ without zero divisors over field $\mathbb K$ are infinite algebraic extensions (or maybe transcendental extensions) over $\mathbb K$?